# vector data loss when exiting a loop

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector, data-loss

i did a very basic and small function to convert a number smaller than 256 to binary

```
void convertToBinary(short decimalNumber, vector<short> &binaryNumber)
{
    short divisor = 128;
    while (decimalNumber != 0)
    {
        short divised = decimalNumber/divisor; // 1
        binaryNumber.push_back(divised);
        if (decimalNumber > divisor)
        {
            decimalNumber -= divisor;
        }
        divisor /= 2;
    }
}
```

but when i try to get the result it always happens to be empty

```
short decimalNumber = 231; //random number
vector<short> binaryNumber;
convertToBinary(decimalNumber, binaryNumber);
for (int i = 0; i < size(binaryNumber); i++)
{
    cout << binaryNumber[i];
}
```

i think i messed up with pointers, but i dont know how to make it work

Comment: Tip: If you're working with `vector` you can always create that in the function and return it. There's no need to require a mutable argument. Even better: Consider your goal of expressing it as textual output. Why not assemble a `std::string`?

Comment: you end up with divisor = 0 and then doing the divide, your programcrashes

Comment: @tadman Since when is `std::vector::len` a thing? [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is perfectly valid here.

Comment: @Nelfeal Sorry, that was the Rust speaking. I meant `length()`.

Comment: @tadman `std::string` has `length`, `std::vector` does not.

Comment: @tadman Thank you! i improved the code and now convertToBinary() returns a string of result, and also i fixed the 0 devisor problem

Comment: @tadmn std::size works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you end up with divisor = 0

this works fine

```
while (decimalNumber != 0 && divisor > 0)
```